# GWT: How to open a Place in a new window

Tags: url, gwt

I want to open a Place in a new browser window. I presume I can just open the URL with Window.open and "_blank". If so, how do I get a URL I can use from a Place I create? I don't want to open the current place, but create the Place object, and use it to determine the URL. I don't see a mapping from Place to a usable URL. I imagine I need to use other methods to build the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use your `PlaceHistoryMapper`, along with `Window.Location`, to build the final URL.

Comment: Could you be more specific? 

I would use g:Hyperlink, but don't see way to specify "_blank" target.

Comment: `Hyperlink` is for internal app navigation. For a _simple_ link, use the `Anchor` widget (or an `<a href="">` in an `HTMLPanel`)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how PlaceHistoryMapper helps, this was the code I used:

String href = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash("myPlaceToken").buildString();
    anchorCustomReports = new Anchor("Open link", href, "_blank");

Comment: PlaceHistoryMapper can give you the "myPlaceToken" from a Place object.